# Delimiting column to get details like date and time

Tags: excel, vba

I have to delimit a column, to get details like date and time, based on space and semicolon(;).

When I do it manually and check the ASCII code (Code=Cell value) for the Date, it is 52 which can be checked in the first sheet.
[image]

When I do it using macro then the ASCII value of date changes to 49 (the macro is in second sheet). Even after changing the format of the date, nothing happens.
[image]

The goal of the exercise is to delimit automatically and then compare the dates in other excel "X" which are in the format like "16-09-2019". Due to auto change of the ASCII value, the two dates (which are in two different sheets) are not coming as equal.

The code I created by recording macro:

```
Columns("A:A").Select
Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("A1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
    TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=True, Tab:=True, _
    Semicolon:=True, Comma:=False, Space:=True, Other:=False, FieldInfo:=_
    Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1), Array(4, 1), Array(5,_ 
    1),Array(6, 1), Array(7, 1), Array(8, 1), Array(9, 1), Array(10,_ 
   1)),TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
```

Comment: Hi BigBen, I have updated the code. I am unable to attach the spreadsheet on which I am working. How can I share it?

Comment: There is no need to attach the spreadsheet itself. Pictures of them (as you provided) and the code (which you now have provided) should be enough information.

Comment: Since column A is a date, probably should be: `FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 4)...`. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.texttocolumns and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlcolumndatatype.

Comment: Damn! It worked. Thank you so much. I spent so much time on this but could not resolve and you solved it in minutes :). This was my first query. Thanks for your very quick solution BigBen

Answer (score 0):

To close this question out:

Specify that column A is in fact a date; see the [`Range.TextToColumns`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.texttocolumns) docs and the [`XlColumnDataType`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlcolumndatatype) enum.`xlDMYFormat` (DMY date format)'s corresponding value is 4.

```
FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 4)...
```

You may want to change the data types for other columns as well.

Comment: I am still working on the code. If I will face any issue related to the data types of other columns then I will post the query once again.Thanks!